# Website looks fine on laptop but messed up on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first attempt at creating a full html page. I developed it on my MacBook, and it looks fine. Mac view:

[image: mac view]

However when I look at it on my desktop, I see:

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://www.gyazo.com/739177573ec613a62073431022240001.png))</sub>

Am I supposed to add something to adjust for a much larger screen size? Would developing on the large screen and viewing on the small screen work better?

Here's the code:

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;

    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #434343;
}

/* Topbar, above navbar */
.topbar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #3cb371;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.topbar .links ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.topbar .links ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.topbar .links ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition:color .4s ease-out;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.topbar .links ul li a:hover
{
    color: #434343;
}

.topbar .links ul li a.active
{
    color: #3cb371;
}

.topbar .links ul li a.active:hover
{
    top: 0px;
}

.navbar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #434343;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.navbar .links
{
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar #brand
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar #brand:hover
{
    margin-left: 25px;
    transition:margin-left .1s ease-out;
}

.navbar .links ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}

.navbar .links ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .links ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition:color .4s ease-out;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar .links ul li a:hover
{
    color: #3cb371;
    top: -2px;
}

.navbar .links ul li a.active
{
    color: #3cb371;
}

.navbar .links ul li a.active:hover
{
    top: 0px;
}




/* jumbotron image */
.largeheading
{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

.largeheading h1
{
    margin-top: -400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.largeheading h3
{
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 330px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.largeheading .contact-btns
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 565px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.largeheading .contact-btns ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.largeheading .contact-btns ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 12px 0px 12px;
}

.largeheading .contact-btns ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition:color .6s ease-out;
    transition:border .5s ease-out;
    display: block;
    padding: 13px 22px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1.6px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.largeheading .contact-btns ul li a:hover
{
    color: #333;
    border: 1.6px solid #3bc371;
}

.nextGallery
{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 230px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nextGallery hr
{
    width: 25%;
}

.gallery
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.gallery .container p
{
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: white;
}

.col-md-4 a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 12px 0px 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.gallery li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition:color .6s ease-out;
    transition:border .6s ease-out;
    display: block;
    padding: 13px 22px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1.6px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.gallery li a:hover
{
    color: #3bc371;
    border: 1.6px solid #3bc371;
}

/*
.jumbotron img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css" />
    <title>Navbar attempt 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="links">
            <ul>
                <li>Call us now (555)-555-5555</li>
                <li>or</li>
                <li><a href="#">Email us today!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/e67b302b7b4ebb7695190d9835bba06b.png" id="brand"></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="largeheading">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="https://emcfinancial.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/plans_blurred.jpg" id="jumbotron-img">
        </div>
        <h1>Your Business Tagline Here</h1>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
 ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerciLorem ipsum dolor sit
 amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</h3>
        <div class="contact-btns">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="nextGallery">
        <h1>Our Gallery</h1>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x350">
                        <p>Gallery item # 1 description here</p>
                    </a>
                    <center><li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li></center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x350">
                        <p>Gallery item # 2 description here</p>
                    </a>
                    <center><li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li></center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x350">
                        <p>Gallery item # 3 description here</p>
                    </a>
                    <center><li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: without code it's hard to tell :)

Comment: Please provide code and tell what browsers or software you are using.

Comment: Most likely your image is not stretching to fill the window width - you can use a bigger image, or you can stretch it with CSS (not recommended). Either way, as per above comments, posting your code is the only way anyone can really offer help.

Comment: Oh god. I thought I did it oops. I also noticed though, when I use jsfiddle or stackoverflow's html/css/js code snippets, it makes things even worse D:. The background color doesn't show, there's extra spaces that I never added, etc. I'll do a jsfiddle as I don't know how to do snippets in a comment (if you even can) [link](https://jsfiddle.net/auz7d93a/) For some reason the background color doesn't show, there's a large gap between the navbar and the large image, etc. @Toby

Comment: Just [edit] your question with the code.

Comment: Done. It also looks weird on here, similar to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For the header with the image, I suggest that you use a percentage for the height for it to be relative to the navigation bar (it seems that it is falling out of it). Then for the image problem, you could try doing this:

```
.img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code on Chrome, firefox, edge, and explorer all looks good. Try saving the code in notepad and opening with a browser to check. The only thing you may want to add are some media queries for different screen sizes. You can learn more about them here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I just checked on chrome and see [this](https://gyazo.com/83eb3c7eab44084ee04f68ef83a27765)

Comment: I'm not sure why. It looks fine in my browser. Have you changed anything?

Comment: Nooe. This is really confusing me. If I stretch out my browser on my mac everything adjusts accordingly. I may recode it on my desktop. The only thing I can think of is that I manually adjusted widths in px rather than a %, but even then it works for everyone else. This is weird

Comment: it looks like you have the jumbotron img in your css commented out. Have you tried removing the uncommenting it?